# Can landspeeders work over water?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Was there any example in canon or legends showing a landspeeder moving over any body of water or swamp? Or any other vehicle that implemented repulsors like the AAT.

Comment: no, you'd need [waterspeeders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QdDqIqGWbo)

Comment: @Edlothiad - shame on you for not knowing the difference between a landspeeder and a speederbike.

Comment: @Tim [hmm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRkFm.jpg)

Comment: @Edlothiad - that would be a landspeeder, yussis.  Speederbikes are what they ride through the forest of Endor.

Comment: @Tim, I meant Mark's Face

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWRQR.png,   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFZeN.png. And my personal favourite, https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtcF5.png

Comment: I'd assume they do, because they have POWER!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Though some of the answers depend on if you would allow airspeeders, they use repulsor lift they just fly higher.

### GAR Infantry Support Platform AKA Swamp Speeder

[image: Swamp Speeder]

The Swamp Speeder as the name suggests is a repulsorlift vehicle that hovers over swamps, modeled after a fan boat by designer TJ Frame.

It can be seen in *Revenge of the Sith* operating on Felucia, a tropical jungle world.

[image: Swamp Speeder On Felucia] [image: Close Up]

### Heavy Missile Platform Droid Gunship

[image: HMP Droid Gunship]

These Confederacy repulsorlift airspeeder were present at the Battle of Kashyyyk and were shown flying over water in *Revenge of the Sith*

[image: Battle of Kashyyyk]

### V-Wing Airspeeder

[image: V Wing]

This New Republic airspeeder was shown to fly over water in the Battle of Mon Calamari in the Legend comic *Dark Empire*

[image: Battle of Mon Cal] [image: Close up]

### Hydra-craft

And from issue #12 of the Marvel Star-wars comic these Hydra-craft

[image: Hydra-craft]

<sup>***Thanks to Valorum***</sup>

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ccEX7IWzjcw/VbUa3IZtlLI/AAAAAAAAaJE/BPnffsJ2-ck/s1600/Star%2BWars%2B%252312%2B-%2Bhydra-skimmer.png - Star Wars #12 (1978)

Comment: @Valorum niceone always forget those comics

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other examples, in Episode I we see two land speeders floating in Theed once Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon surface (3 minutes 30 seconds).

They look exactly like some of the models we see later in the movie on Tatooine. They seem to not only be able to hover on the water, but in some cases, float when parked.

On the same planet, there are Gondola Speeders, only seen once in the movie. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gondola_speeder